# SWI-Prolog: No permission to load source when "Non-module file" already loaded into some module)

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

This error may be a duplicate of

[SWI Prolog ensure_loaded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518216/swi-prolog-ensure-loaded-error)

Since that question is not fully answered, I decide to post mine here.

There are some dynamic loaded files using `<name>:compile(Filename)` clause, which I suspect could be a reason for the error.

```
➜  chill git:(master) ✗ swipl --traditional                                                                                                                                              [18/06/20| 8:54AM]
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.6.4)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- expects_dialect(sicstus).
true.
?- consult('chill-test.pl').
true.  
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
true.
?- run_trials('orig-db', 'raw250-split1.pl', 'orig-db-evaluate', 25, 200, 'raw250-res1.out').
Reading Split File: raw250-split1.pl
Specializing with 25 top-level examples
Beginning Example Analysis
Attempting Example 1 ....
<omitted output>    
BEGINING INDUCTION: 1 5
    ERROR: No permission to load source `'/home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/orig-db.i'' (Non-module file already loaded into module test; trying to load into thetheory)
    ERROR: In:
    ERROR:   [36] throw(error(permission_error(load,source,'/home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/orig-db.i'),context(...,'Non-module file already loaded into module test; trying to load into thetheory')))
    ERROR:   [34] '$assert_load_context_module'('/home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/orig-db.i',thetheory,[expand(false),...]) at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/boot/init.pl:2439
    ERROR:   [33] '$mt_do_load'(<clause>(0x559a46329ea0),'orig-db.i','/home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/orig-db.i',thetheory,[expand(false),...]) at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/boot/init.pl:2069
    ERROR:   [32] setup_call_catcher_cleanup(system:with_mutex('$load_file',...),system:'$mt_do_load'(<clause>(0x559a46329ea0),'orig-db.i','/home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/orig-db.i',thetheory,...),_142002,system:'$mt_end_load'(<clause>(0x559a46329ea0))) at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/boot/init.pl:443
    ERROR:   [21] make_theory('orig-db.i',op/2,_142072) at /home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/spchillin-nr.pl:966
    ERROR:   [20] top_induction('orig-db.i',[op(...,_142120)],[op(...,_142132),...|...],_142108) at /home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/spchillin-nr.pl:129
    ERROR:   [19] chill_lib:cpu_time(user:top_induction('orig-db.i',...,...,_142186),_142170) at /home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/chill_lib.pl:136
    ERROR:   [18] induce_control_definition('orig-db.i',[op(...,_142230)],[op(...,_142242),...|...],_142216,_142218) at /home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/chill.pl:109
    ERROR:   [17] add_each_optimization(cxit([...|...]),'orig-db.i',fail,[(... :- ...),...],[],_142282,_142284) at /home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/chill.pl:85
    ERROR:   [14] add_rules_for_targets([tr(...,function,fail)],'orig-db.i',[... - ...,...|...],[],[],_142346,_142348) at /home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/chill.pl:79
    ERROR:   [12] chill_lib:cpu_time(user:create_optimized_rules(...,'orig-db.i',_142426,_142428),_142412) at /home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/chill_lib.pl:136
    ERROR:   [11] chill_specialize('orig-db','<garbage_collected>','orig-db.i','orig-db-opt.pl') at /home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/chill.pl:11
    ERROR:    [9] run_trials_loop(25,'orig-db',225,200,[[...],...|...],[ti(...,...,...),...|...],'raw250-res1.out') at /home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/chill-test.pl:188
    ERROR:    [7] <user>
    ERROR: 
    ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
    ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
    ^  Exception: (32) setup_call_catcher_cleanup(system:with_mutex('$load_file', '$mt_start_load'('/home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/orig-db.i', <clause>(0x559a46329ea0), [expand(false), expand(true)])), system:'$mt_do_load'(<clause>(0x559a46329ea0), 'orig-db.i', '/home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/orig-db.i', thetheory, [expand(false), expand(true)]), _142584, system:'$mt_end_load'(<clause>(0x559a46329ea0))) ? creep
    ^  Call: (34) call(system:'$mt_end_load'(<clause>(0x559a46329ea0))) ? creep
    ^  Exit: (34) call(system:'$mt_end_load'(<clause>(0x559a46329ea0))) ? creep
```

There are two dynamic compiled modules `test` and `thetheory`. They are **both compiled from the same file** `orig-db.i`.

If I force one of them to **read from a different file** like `orig-db.ii`, the error will be different.

**I tried the same code with `yap`, it didn't complain with this error.**

```
➜  chill git:(master) ✗ yap                                                      [18/06/20| 9:21AM]
% Restoring file /usr/lib/Yap/startup.yss
YAP 6.2.2 (x86_64-linux): Sat Sep 17 13:59:03 UTC 2016
   ?- consult('chill-test.pl').
yes
   ?- run_trials('orig-db', 'raw250-split1.pl', 'orig-db-evaluate', 25, 200, 'raw250-res1.out').
<omitted output>
BEGINING INDUCTION: 1 5
 % reconsulting /home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/orig-db.i...
 % reconsulted /home/vimos/git/SP/mooney/chill/orig-db.i in module thetheory, 0 msec 1344 bytes
Induction Time: 0.00

op(ps([traverse(pvar(1),freevar):[],const(pvar(1),riverid(mississippi)):[mississippi],answer(pvar(0),state(pvar(0))):[which,through]],[run,?]),G9) :-
   db_lib:coref_vars(traverse,2,2,answer,2,1,ps([traverse(pvar(1),freevar):[],const(pvar(1),riverid(mississippi)):[mississippi],answer(pvar(0),state(pvar(0))):[which,through]],[run,?]),G9).
op(A,B) :-
   introduce(density(_,_),[density],A,B).
op(A,B) :-
   db_lib:coref_vars(density,2,1,state,1,1,A,B).
op(A,B) :-
   db_lib:coref_vars(density,2,2,smallest,2,1,A,B).
op(A,B) :-
   db_lib:lift_conj(state,1,smallest,2,2,A,B).
op(A,B) :-
   db_lib:drop_conj(density,2,smallest,2,2,A,B).
```

Replacing `ensure_loaded` to `reconsult` does not solve the error in `Swi-Prolog`.

I need some hint to understand this error, is this an implementation issue of `Swi-Prolog`?

If you want to try it, the code can be found from the ftp url below.

Thank you for the help!

---

*I am trying to migrate an earlier code to `SWI-Prolog`, which was written in
`SICStus 3 #3: Thu Sep 12 09:54:27 CDT 1996` or earlier
by Raymond J. Mooney ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/mooney/chill/. 
All the questions with this tag are all related to this task. I'm new to prolog, helps and suggestions are welcomed!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documented, current limitation of SWI-Prolog, related to its make mechanism. A possible workaround is to **duplicate** the `orig-db.i` file. This way the two modules, `test` and `thetheory`, will be loading different files.

Comment: Good to know this! I searched their website, maybe not using the right key word. Thank you!

Comment: See http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=consulting footnote 47.